# Linked Server in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to create a Linked Server from `SQL2` to `SQL1` but I get errors such as

> Login failed for user 'USER\a-Djbril'

This is `SQL2` details:

```
SRV_NAME    SRV_PROVIDERNAME    SRV_PRODUCT SRV_DATASOURCE  SRV_PROVIDERSTRING  SRV_LOCATION    SRV_CAT
SQL2    SQLNCLI SQL2    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

This is `SQL1` details:

```
SRV_NAME    SRV_PROVIDERNAME    SRV_PRODUCT SRV_DATASOURCE  SRV_PROVIDERSTRING  SRV_LOCATION    SRV_CAT
SQL1    SQLNCLI SQL Server   SQL1   NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I run this script below and the command run successfully.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server=N'SQL1',           
   @srvproduct=N'',               
   @provider=N'SQLNCLI',            
   @datasrc=N'SQL1',
   @catalog = 'Primary'
```

But when I run:

```
 EXEC Sp_testlinkedserver SQL1
```

I got the error:

> Login failed for user 'USER\a-Djbril'.

I don't have user and password to both SQL I go through Windows Authentication. I think SQL has an issue with my Login and Security. I am at a loss and not sure what I need to do. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The user you are running as needs to exist on the remote server with proper permissions. You can script this to use a specific user on the other server if you provide the username and password.

Comment: It looks like linked server is working... that user just needs to be permissioned on the remote server.

Comment: I run this script but it didnt work thats when it said "Login Failed for user 'USER\a-Djbril':   EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'SQL1', 'false', 'USER\a-Djbril', 'a-Djbril', 'London123'

Comment: The user needs access on the SQL1 server. it looks like everything else is fine but it cannot login on the remote server.

Comment: Looks like you might need to talk to your [database administrator](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: For SQL1 my user name is USER\Djbril and for SQL2 its USER\a-Djbril does that have an affect?

Comment: Yes, that makes a difference. You'll have to use that user name and the appropriate password for that database rather than Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You do need a proper login at the target server. It can be a SQL user or you windows login if both server are at same domain.
For your specific example you re trying to connect with target server by using a non existent SQL user.

Please refer to this link if you wish to connect using a windows account.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0bce262a-c302-4508-81e6-c67b70e3c1b8/linked-server-using-windows-authentication-and-local-system-network-service-account?forum=sqlsecurity